# Express.js: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'call'

Tags: node.js, methods, express

after install Express.js, I wrote this on node:

```
var express = require('express'), app =express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.router);
});
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hola mundo');
});

app.listen(3020);
console.log('Hola Mundo');
```

And I can see the message "Hola Mundo" when I start the app, but when I make the petition I received this:

```
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'call'
    at Object.router [as handle] (/home/alumno/Escritorio/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/router.js:96:6)
    at next (/home/alumno/Escritorio/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:203:15)
    at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/home/alumno/Escritorio/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:88:61)
    at next (/home/alumno/Escritorio/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:203:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/home/alumno/Escritorio/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:35:5)
    at next (/home/alumno/Escritorio/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:203:15)
    at Object.handle (/home/alumno/Escritorio/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/http.js:84:5)
    at next (/home/alumno/Escritorio/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:203:15)
    at HTTPServer.handle (/home/alumno/Escritorio/nodejs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:216:3)
    at HTTPServer.emit (events.js:70:17)
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: I'd recommend copying the example directly from the express website, and doing `rm node_modules; npm install express` just to make sure everything is the latest version.

Comment: when does the error happen? what petition?

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
It's the same example from the express guide. And I meant the http petition, sorry for my bad English.
It works perfectly without the router line, thanks. But I wonder why I had to keep that line, if I have node and express updated and I just copy exactly the example code from the Express page? Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `app.use(express.router)` and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
It's the same example from the express guide. And I meant the http petition, sorry for my bad English.
It works perfectly without the router line, thanks. But I wonder why I had to keep that line, if I have node and express updated and I just copy exactly the example code from the Express page? Greetings

Comment: Because express is under active development, sometimes the docs can get a little out of sync with the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you're using `express.router` not `app.router`.

Answer (score 0):

try using the express-validator module. Can be found 
[here](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator)

like this

```
 var   expressValidator         = require('express-validator');
 app.use(expressValidator());
```